# Join tables from two different periods using wildcard tables in BQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table (so-called meta) that looks like:

| experiment_id | start_date | end_date | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20531 | 2022-07-25 | 2022-09-01 | 59ae0e4530e40e40e |
| 20531 | 2022-07-25 | 2022-09-01 | 3ff80f0e42fa1f067 |
| 20531 | 2022-07-25 | 2022-09-01 | fffd9a8146a1da86b |
| 18263 | 2022-05-08 | 2022-06-04 | 4198825ca57449e5a |
| 18263 | 2022-05-08 | 2022-06-04 | ba23c2eb65423c476 |
| 18263 | 2022-05-08 | 2022-06-04 | fffa6064826d65336 |
| 16517 | 2022-03-04 | 2022-04-04 | fffa6826d65064064 |
| 16517 | 2022-03-04 | 2022-04-04 | cb2afcb2afcb2afcb |
| 16517 | 2022-03-04 | 2022-04-04 | 9ce44a9ce44a9ce44 |

each user is found on each particular period across experiments, so user 59ae0e4530e40e40e can be found on experiment_id 20531 and within [start_date, end_date]

This table contains around 35M users and approx 30 experiments (each experiment with different number of users.

I am trying to retrieve some other metrics from two periods from another wildcard partitioned table containing 7d aggregated data:

- Previous week to start of experiment
- Last week of the experiment

It takes a lot of time joining and/or filtering. Is there a way
to optimize it?

This is the query I am using:

```
 WITH meta as (
  SELECT user_id, 
  experiment_id
  meta_start_date,
  meta_end_date
  FROM meta
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
),

wau_pre as (
SELECT
  user_id,
  SUM(IF(metric = 'value1', metric_ms, 0)) as metric1_ms_7d,
  SUM(IF(metric = 'value2', metric_ms, 0)) as metric2_ms_7d
FROM 
  `my_metric_7d_aggregate_v3_*`
INNER JOIN 
  meta 
  USING(user_id)
WHERE CAST(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS DATE) = DATE_SUB(meta_start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)  
GROUP BY 
  user_id), 

wau_post as (
SELECT
  user_id,
  SUM(IF(metric = 'value1', metric_ms, 0)) as metric1_ms_7d,
  SUM(IF(metric = 'value2', metric_ms, 0)) as metric2_ms_7d
FROM 
  `my_metric_7d_aggregate_v3_*`
INNER JOIN 
  meta 
  USING(user_id)
WHERE CAST(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS DATE) = meta_end_date 
GROUP BY 
  user_id)

SELECT
  meta.user_id,
  IF(wau_pre.user_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) as wau_pre_treat,
  IF(wau_post.user_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) as wau_post_treat,
  IFNULL(wau_pre.metric1_ms_7d, 0) / 60000 as metric1_mins_pre_treat_7d,
  IFNULL(wau_pre.metric2_ms_7d, 0) / 60000 as metric2_mins_pre_treat_7d,
  IFNULL(wau_post.metric1_ms_7d, 0) / 60000 as metric1_mins_post_treat_7d,
  IFNULL(wau_post.metric2_ms_7d, 0) / 60000 as metric2_mins_post_treat_7d,
FROM 
  exposed_users
LEFT JOIN 
  wau_pre 
  USING(user_id)
LEFT JOIN 
  wau_post 
  USING(user_id)
```

EDIT: Based on @AlienDeg answer, I decided to move the WHERE clause to the condition of the JOIN. Now my question is, is it possible to join on user_id and when _TABLE_SUFFIX is start date OR end_date ?

```
WITH meta as (
  SELECT user_id, 
  experiment_id
  meta_start_date,
  meta_end_date
  FROM meta
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
),

wau as (
SELECT
  user_id,
  CASE 
    WHEN CAST(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS DATE) = DATE_SUB(meta.meta_start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 'wau_pre_treat' 
    WHEN CAST(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS DATE) = meta.meta_end_date THEN 'wau_post_treat' 
  END period_treatment,
  SUM(IF(metric = 'value1', metric_ms, 0)) as metric1_ms_7d,
  SUM(IF(metric = 'value2', metric_ms, 0)) as metric2_ms_7d
FROM 
  `my_metric_7d_aggregate_v3_*` metric_aggr_7d
LEFT JOIN 
  meta 
ON  metric_aggr_7d.user_id = meta.user_id AND 
  (CAST(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS DATE) = DATE_SUB(meta.meta_start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) OR
   CAST(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS DATE) = meta.meta_end_date)
GROUP BY 
  user_id) 

SELECT
  meta.user_id,
  period_treatment,
  IFNULL(wau_pre.metric1_ms_7d, 0) / 60000 as metric1_mins_pre_treat_7d,
  IFNULL(wau_pre.metric2_ms_7d, 0) / 60000 as metric2_mins_pre_treat_7d,
  IFNULL(wau_post.metric1_ms_7d, 0) / 60000 as metric1_mins_post_treat_7d,
  IFNULL(wau_post.metric2_ms_7d, 0) / 60000 as metric2_mins_post_treat_7d,
FROM 
  wau
```

On the other hand, given that metric_aggr_7d contains 1500 partitions (days) I was also wondering:

Wouldn't it be more optimal to retrieve the users from metric_aggr_7d by dates (for example: metric_aggr_7d_20220724 and metric_aggr_7d_20220901 for exp_id 20531, metric_aggr_7d_20220507 and metric_aggr_7d_20220604 for exp_id 18263, etc) and then join with the meta table after? Is it the same performance?

The only thing I don't know is how to get fields from other CTE to use them in another CTE, because start and end_date are in the meta table and I want to filter `my_metric_7d_aggregate_v3_*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = start_date -1 OR _TABLE_SUFFIX = end_date. I couldn't join because there is no field in common.

Comment: Mysql and google bigquery are two different products. Since mysql does not have a parse_date() function, I assume you are using bigquery.

Comment: yes, it is bigquery @Shadow

Answer (score 0):

yeah, feels like simple fix would be moving your where clause to the join condition.

```
WITH meta as (
  SELECT user_id AS meta_user_id,  
  experiment_id
  meta_start_date,
  meta_end_date
  FROM meta
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
),

wau_pre as (
SELECT
  user_id,
  SUM(IF(metric = 'value1', metric_ms, 0)) as metric1_ms_7d,
  SUM(IF(metric = 'value2', metric_ms, 0)) as metric2_ms_7d
FROM 
  `my_metric_7d_aggregate_v3_*`
INNER JOIN 
  meta 
  ON user_id = meta_user_id
  AND CAST(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS DATE) = DATE_SUB(meta_start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)  
GROUP BY 
  user_id), 

wau_post as (
SELECT
  user_id,
  SUM(IF(metric = 'value1', metric_ms, 0)) as metric1_ms_7d,
  SUM(IF(metric = 'value2', metric_ms, 0)) as metric2_ms_7d
FROM 
  `my_metric_7d_aggregate_v3_*`
INNER JOIN 
  meta 
  ON user_id=meta_user_id
AND CAST(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS DATE) = meta_end_date 
GROUP BY 
  user_id)

SELECT
  exposed_users.user_id,
  IF(wau_pre.user_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) as wau_pre_treat,
  IF(wau_post.user_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) as wau_post_treat,
  IFNULL(wau_pre.metric1_ms_7d, 0) / 60000 as metric1_mins_pre_treat_7d,
  IFNULL(wau_pre.metric2_ms_7d, 0) / 60000 as metric2_mins_pre_treat_7d,
  IFNULL(wau_post.metric1_ms_7d, 0) / 60000 as metric1_mins_post_treat_7d,
  IFNULL(wau_post.metric2_ms_7d, 0) / 60000 as metric2_mins_post_treat_7d,
FROM 
  exposed_users
LEFT JOIN 
  wau_pre 
  USING(user_id)
LEFT JOIN 
  wau_post 
  USING(user_id)
```

Comment: I think that's an option! You inspired me, thanks! Could you take a look at my edit? I optimised the query merging pre_wau and post_wau CTE. @Aliendeg

Comment: Does it actually run faster when you have everything together? feels like it's gonna be slower when you pack everything in one subquery. also readability is a little bit worse